# How does Google select users for the staggered roll-outs in the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, in-app-update, app-update

I can't find Google's update policy for staggered roll-outs. If I have multiple staggered roll-outs, for example, staggered roll-outs at 20%. Does Google update the same users or does Google **randomly** re-select the updated users for **each** update cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From previous experience with my app, sometimes I am in the 20% and sometimes not. So it appears that for each release users are randomly selected.